# Cannot step into a particular function in a library in Xcode 4.2/iOS 5.0

Tags: ios, debugging, xcode4, debug-symbols

I am working on an iPhone app in which I need to include a library (lib.a) for the app to work. This library (lib.a) consists of multiple files(classes). While debugging, I noticed that I **could not step into** any function in the file sync.m (included via lib.a), but I **could step into** any function in file (data.m) (also included via lib.a). I am wondering as to why I can step into one file and not another. I am using XCode4.2/iOS 5.0

I have checked all the debug settings in both my app and the library. 
Generate Debug Symbols => yes (for debug)
I am also in the "run for debug mode".

The only thing that I suspect at this point is that I moved  the sync.m from one folder to another ... Would that cause a problem with respect to the debug symbols ??? Where are the debug symbols stored? In the dsym file? Where can I find this file as I would like to see which debug symbols are being generated and which are not.

I would appreciate it if anyone can throw some light on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object was not being retained and thus was pointing to nothing(NULL). Obviously, therefore function couldn't be stepped into.